# Help with the following error: Variable already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, rnn, text-generation

I am not sure how to handle this error. This is from an RNN tutorial found [here](https://github.com/hunkim/word-rnn-tensorflow).

I vaguely understand that the variables need to be able to be reused, but I don't know how to implement this fix. Train.py ran for several hours and finished successfully; this particular error comes when running sample.py

Given the long training time, I would very much like to get this working, rather than starting over.

> ```
> ValueError: Variable rnnlm/softmax_w already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:
>   File "C:\Users\wlt42\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
>     self._traceback = _extract_stack()
>   File "C:\Users\wlt42\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
>     original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
>   File "C:\Users\wlt42\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
>     op_def=op_def)
> ```